# How to generate sample from bimodal distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, simulation

Is there any "classical" distribution that is considered bimodal?
For example, "Normal" is unimodal, "Gamma" is unimodal.

If I have to generate a sample of 100 numbers from a univariate bimodal distribution, how should I proceed with that? I think that "sticking" two samples from unimodal distributions doesn't really work, or am I wrong?

Will a sample created from sticking two random samples be considered independent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, [*beta distributions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with both shape parameters below 1 are bimodal. The support of a beta distribution is $(0,1),$ and these beta distributions have
probability concentrated near $0$ and $1$.

Second, [*mixtures of normal distributions*](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s10259.pdf) can be bimodal, roughly speaking, if the two normal
distributions being mixed have means that are several standard deviations apart.
For example, a 50:50 mixture of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=5, \sigma=2)$ and
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=10, \sigma=1)$ is noticeably bimodal. (The mixture
distribution is has a density function that is the average of the density
functions of the two distributions being mixed. If the two SDs are equal, you
may want to investigate the exact separation between the means for bimodality.)

> I'm not sure what you mean by 'sticking' samples together. Certainly,
> if you just concatenate a sample of size 50 from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ with a
> sample of size 50 from $\mathsf{Unif}(2,4),$ you will get a bimodal
> histogram with 100 observations, but I personally wouldn't consider that to be random sampling from a bimodal distribution. If you randomly select 100 times from one of two different random samples (each of size 100) at each step, then the result is a random sample from a mixture distribution, which may be bimodal.

Here is R code to get samples of size $n = 500$ from a beta distribution and a bimodal normal
mixture distribution, along with histograms of the two datasets, with the
bivariate densities superimposed.

Notes: (1) I use $n = 500$ instead of $n = 100$ just for
illustration, so you can see that the histograms are close to matching the
bimodal densities. (2) This is very simplistic R code, which you should adapt
to whatever software you're using and to your degree of sophistication using it.
(3) I don't know if you are allowed to use pre-programed functions, such as
`rbeta` and `rnorm`, that sample from specific distributions, or whether
you are supposed to use the inverse-CDF method with uniform observations.

```
 set.seed(1234)                            # include seed for same samples
 n = 500;  x1 = rbeta(n, .5, .4)
 y1 = rnorm(n, 5, 2);  y2 = rnorm(n, 10, 1)
 w = rbinom(n, 1, .5)                      # 50:50 random choice
 x2 = w*y1 + (1-w)*y2                      # normal mixture
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))                         # two panels per plot
   hist(x1, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="BETA(.5, .4)");  rug(x1)
     curve(dbeta(x, .5, .4), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
   hist(x2, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Normal Mixture"); rug(x2)
     curve(.5*dnorm(x,5,2)+.5*dnorm(x,10,1), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))                         # return to default single panel
```

[image]

**Addendum:** (After Comments) It seems you define a bimodal PDF to mean two
achieved maximums of equal height. Slight modifications in the code are
as follows, with additional comments at the changes:

```
set.seed(1235)                            
n = 2000;  u1 = rbeta(n, .5, .5)           # 2000 wasteful, but simple
cond = u1 > .01 & u1 < .99                   
v1 = u1[cond];  x1 = v1[1:500]             # truncate and use 500
n = 500; y1 = rnorm(n, 2, 2);  y2 = rnorm(n, 12, 2)  # same SD
w = rbinom(n, 1, .5)                     
x2 = w*y1 + (1-w)*y2                      
par(mfrow=c(1,2))                       
  hist(x1, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Truncated BETA(.5, .5)");  rug(x1)
    k = diff(pbeta(c(.01,.99),.5,.5))      # adj for truncation
    curve((1/k)*dbeta(x, .5, .5),.01,.99, lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
  hist(x2, prob=T, col="skyblue2",ylim=c(0,.1), main="Normal Mixture"); rug(x2)
    curve(.5*dnorm(x,2,2)+.5*dnorm(x,12,2), lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: [+1] very informative answer. One could indicate to the OP the importance of  arcsine distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution) which is $\beta(1/2,1/2)$ very close to your example...

Comment: Good idea. Especially apt if OP need to do inverse CDF of uniform instead of `rbeta`. CDF of arcsine dist'n easy to invert. And then there is Feller's Arcsine Law. Sometimes discussions of bimodal distributions give only symmetrical examples, and I wanted to illustrate asymmetrical ones.

Comment: The link that you gave about the mixture of two normal distributions was very helpful. However, I still have a concern about Beta. According to the definition that I found in Wikipedia, a mode of a continuous prob. distribution is a value at which the pdf attains its maximum value. For Beta distribution with parameters smaller than 1, the maximum isn't attained. I also found that definitions of what a mode is are different depending on whether we refer to a pdf or to a data set. I understand that the generated values will be concentrated about x=0 and x=1, but those values won't be attained.

Comment: Usually bimodal means the PDF has two maxima, not necessarily of the same height. But if you want two maxima of the "same height," use a mixed normal in which the SDs are both $\sigma$ and the means differ by $5\sigma.$ If the asymptotic behavior at 0 and 1 in $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5)$ bothers you, truncate to $[.1, .9].$ (That is use acceptance-rejection, accepting only values in $[.1, .9].$)

Comment: See Addendum implementing these slight modifications, except that the symmetrical beta is truncated to $[.01, .99].$

Comment: @BruceET Thank you. I am not very familiar with the idea of "acceptance-region". My concern was indeed that in case of $Beta(0.5, 0.5)$ the maxima aren't attained, so I believe this contradicts the definition of the mode that I have (that is, it's the maximum of a pdf). What do you mean by "trancate it"? Do you mean that I have to restrict the domain from (0,1) to (.1, .9)?

Comment: Lines 2-4 of Addendum code. // Generate (way) more realizations of BETA(.5,.5) than you need. Reject (ignore) those outside (.01,.99), keep as many survivors as you need to get desired count.// Not arguing with your strict def'n of 'bimodal', but I know of no statistician who wouldn't view BETA(.5,.5) as bimodal, or would insist 'modes' be the same height. In gen'l, I don't think there's an agreed-upon strict def'n. Certainly, the 50:50 normal mixture in my Addendum ought to meet the strictest possible def'n.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks a lot. I am too new to thus stuff.